# Block pornography directly on network router

Tags: website-blocker

I want to set myself free from pornography, and I'm looking for a piece of SW or SW technique to achieve such goal. I know that not going to those websites might be the solution, but I'm looking for some piece of SW or SW technique on the **WIFI/LAN router**, which it would be optimal to block adult content within all the network, and which it would be more designed to the network itself and not particularly to a computer's children.

Which SW technique would you suggest me to block pornography directly on the network router? Are you aware of any router that has already such SW?

Comment: Can you define "pornography", because, if you cannot then you cannot block it? good luck in not blocking too much or too little. See https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/sep/09/facebook-reinstates-napalm-girl-photo

Comment: @Mawg of course that defining clearly, directly and unambiguously "pornography" is rocket science! Though it should not be hard to a have a comprehensive list of all websites with such content.

Comment: My reply was getting long, so I moved it to an answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest Way to filter out porn (or other content) via the network router is to use a namesever (DNS) with a blacklist.

A free solution is for this openddns family shield.

### How to Setup opendns with family filter

**You first need to [signup for an account here](https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/).** You will get the
FamilyShield OpenDNS server addresses after you signed up.

setup-guide from the [opdennds website](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/228006487-FamilyShield-Router-Configuration-Instructions) :

> Here are our generalized router configuration:
>
> 1. Open the preferences for your router.
>
> Often, the preferences are set in your web browser, via a URL with
> numbers (example: http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.1.1). You may
> need a password.
>
> If you set the router password long time ago and cannot remember it
> now, you can often reset the password to the manufacturer default by
> pressing a button on the router itself.
>
> Or preferences may be set via specific application for your router,
> which you installed on your computer when you added the router.
> 2. Find the DNS server settings.   Scan for the letters DNS next to a field which allows two or three sets of numbers, each broken into four
> groups of one to three numbers. It might look like this:
>
> 3. Put in the FamilyShield OpenDNS server addresses as your DNS server settings and save/apply.
>
> Please write down your current settings before entering the OpenDNS
> addresses, just in case.
>
> ```
> 208.67.222.123
> 208.67.220.123
> ```
>
> 4. Test your Settings
>
> Browse to https://welcome.opendns.com/. If you have successfully set
> your public DNS to the our servers, you will see "Welcome to
> OpenDNS!".

there are other (paid) options for a DNS with a family filter that can be setup in the same way.

### using openwrt

Since you asked for a Softwaresolution: [openwrt](https://openwrt.org/) is a free and open firmware for routers. It will let you control the router like a mini-computer(which a router is). So you can install a firewall/filter there ([example guide](https://blog.chris007.de/openwrt-as-internet-filter-for-e-g-kids/) ).

There is a [list of supported devices](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start) on the openwrt website. The TP-Link TL-WR841ND is an cheap router that will work for your purpose.

### buying special hardware

A lot of routers offer the option of a "family filter" or have one enabled by default, which is what you are looking for. If you search online for "router with family filter" you will find many (overprized) options there. If you look for and easy way, that might be it, though I think setting up opendns is faster and gratis.

If you allready own a rasberrypie, or want to buy one, you can achive the same (or even better) result with the software [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) like  [explained here](https://chadmayfield.com/2017/06/29/blocking-porn-with-pihole/). you will essentially make the rasberrpie act as your router and get an addblocker as a free bonus to your pornblocker.

### blocking on the client

There are many,many pornblockers out there that work on the client.
A often recommended solution is [k9 webprotection](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/). Again a websearch will turn up many viable alternatives

Comment: I will wait some time to test it, and if not other answers are provided I set your answer as the accepted answer! We should wait! Thank you a lot

Comment: btw, I didn't say it had to be free, I'm might pay for some better service! Thanks a lot

Comment: opendns is good and free. I have also included alternatives for the sake of completeness

Comment: If you have multiple computers behind it you also need to make sure that no other DNS resolver can be used, because if any computer is set up to use 8.8.8.8 or any other nonfiltering resolver then access will be granted despite your efforts. Which may mean you need to filter out DNS queries.

Comment: "The easiest Way to filter out ***SOME*** porn ..."

Answer (score 3):

opendns is free and reliable.  Adding in family shield blocks everything you are intending to block.

However, I want to share some other options out there to block the content at the router.

Norton ConnectSafe is another option.  There are 3 levels of blocking.

- Policy 1: Security) This policy block all sites hosting malware, phishing sites, and scam sites.
  Those DNS entries are 199.85.126.10 & 199.85.127.10.
- Policy 2: Security + Porn) In addition to blocking unsafe sites, this policy also blocks access to sites that contain sexually explicit material.
  Those DNS entries are 199.85.126.20 & 199.85.127.20.
- Policy 3: Security + Other) In addition to blocking unsafe sites and porn sites, this policy also blocks access to sites that feature mature content, abortion, alcohol, crime, cults, drugs, gambling, hate, sexual orientation, suicide, tobacco or violence.
  Those DNS entries are 199.85.126.30 & 199.85.127.30.

[site link](https://dns.norton.com/faq.html)

Comment: is Norton ConnectSafe free?

Comment: If you want a free solution, you should add the [tag:gratis] tag, or you should state your budget - on every question which you ask

Comment: @Mawg I didn't say I wanted it free, I just asked whether norton is free or not.

Comment: IGTFY : the first words of [the web page](https://connectsafe.norton.com/) say "Norton ConnectSafe is a free service that provides a first layer of defense by blocking unsafe sites automatically."  However, if you won't be accepting this as the answer,it is still a good idea to either to update your question to either add the [tag:gratis] tag or to state a budget. The more information that you give us, the more that we can help you.

Comment: Free service for you to use.

Answer (score 1):

My comment was getting  rather long, so I will post this as an answer.

Tldr; The answer is "***AIN'T GONNA HAPPEN***.

---

I asked you in comments

> Can you define "pornography", because, if you cannot then you cannot
>   block it? Good luck in not blocking too much or too little.
>
> See
>   https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/sep/09/facebook-reinstates-napalm-girl-photo

and you replied

> of course that defining clearly, directly and unambiguously
>   "pornography" is rocket science! Though it should not be hard to a
>   have a comprehensive list of all websites with such content.

(these two statements seem to contradict each other)

LOLX! [I know it when I see it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it) - but can you explain that to your router?

As to "it should not be hard to a have a comprehensive list of all websites with such content" - I am *astonished* that *anyone* can be so naive. There are [this many](http://www.internetlivestats.com/total-number-of-websites/) web sites (currently 1.2 ***billion***) and more than one new domain is created ***every second***. Who is going to look at those and decide if they need to be on your router's list?

To reiterate, the true answer is "***AIN'T GONNA HAPPEN***.

---

Now, if you care to rephrase you questions along the line of "how do I get my router to refuse to serve certain sites?", then you have answers above, such as that from @Nivatius

You could ask a separate question, maybe here, maybe on our sister site https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ requesting a list of "all the porn sites in the world". After the laughter dies down, you might well get a few lists, which might be helpful.

***BUT***, you state "I want to set myself free from pornography" - so, you have to accept that technology can *never* do that for you. It is a matter of self discipline (I am not trying to make that sound easy; I am just defining what it the only possible solution).

I don't know if seeing unexpected pornographic adds upsets you. If so, you can blacklist sites which show such ads, one by one, as you encounter them).

If it is a matter of self control, then accept that even if you did achieve what you wanted with your router (impossible as it is), you probably have a data allowance on your 'phone, and could use that, or you might find free WiFi in shopping malls, libraries, or even at work - which might lead to some embarrassing situations, and even more awkward questions on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Again - you ***will not*** find a technical solution.

Perhaps some other sister sites like https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/ or even https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ , although this is not strictly interpersonal.

I hope that I have not come over as too hard. And, without knowing your motives, it is not easy to answer, but a router based solution will, at best only ***reduce*** exposure to pr0n, and can never eliminate it.

Comment: +1 though artificial inteliggence algorithms might do the trick. We're dealing then in the field of probability, taking into account Heuristics. If one finds a method that assures that adult content is 99% of the times blocked, and that 95% of the valid content is not blocked, I'm already satisfied. Pattern recognition techniques also play then an importan role, I suppose. And seeing a naked girl due to a napalm attack on a B&W picture is way too different than observing a HD colourful video of sexual intercourse.

Comment: which nevertheless means, that if I get such picture of the naked girl blocked, I dont mind losing that picture, if I know that all the other porn content is most likely also blocked.

Comment: in any case, you're totally right, self-control is the key factor

Comment: If you want Bayesian logic, you ought to add that to the question. Bear in mind that it will show you pictures, more at first, fewer as you train it, asking "is this pornography".

Comment: Machine learning then. Thousands of potential users might do the trick! LIke Google uses on "I'm a human" captacha to recognize patterns on their Street View, such as shops or signals!

Comment: Lolx !  That's a  great idea (+1) ! But I am not so sure that my partner would like it